# How to make ListBox automatically add a ScrollBar and not change the height of the Listbox?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, uiscrollview, listboxitem

How to make ListBox automatically add a scrollBar, not change the height of the Listbox, when the content is updated?

I made a form that stretches and allows you to see more rows in the ListBox element. But when I add many items to the ListBox at once, the height of the ListBox increases and the foreground goes below the screen. If I pull the form with my hand a scrollbar appears and everything looks proofreader.

I want to achieve the window behavior that:

1. Will stretch the ListBox if we stretch the window by hand
2. Will not increase the height of the Listbox when adding items, but will immediately add a srollbar

start view:
[image]

wrong view after adding items:
[image]

perfect view after adding items:
[image]

xaml code:

```xml
        <DockPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   MinHeight="80"
                   LastChildFill="True">
            <ListBox x:Name="ListFolders"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                     VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                     Margin="8 0"
                     ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedDirectories}"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFolder}"
                     MouseDoubleClick="ListBox_MouseDoubleClick"
                     KeyDown="ListFolders_KeyDown">
            </ListBox>

        </DockPanel>
```

1. embed ListBox in different types of elements such as DockPanel? Canvas StackPanel
2. use ListBox without wrappers
3. tried the ScrollView settings

full code:

```
<Window x:Class="B.Revit.BatchUpgrader.Addin.Views.BatchUpgraderWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:B.Revit.BatchUpgrader.Addin.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Batch Upgrader 1.0"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    ResizeMode="CanResize"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    ShowInTaskbar="False"
    Topmost="True">

<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="32"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkSeaGreen"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF9DA57F" Background="#FFF4F7E9">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Margin="4">

        <GroupBox Header="File Types"
                  Margin="4">
            <StackPanel>
                <CheckBox Content="Project files *.rvt"
                          Margin="4"
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsProjectUpdate}" />
                <CheckBox Content="Family files *.rfa"
                          Margin="4"
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsFamilyUpdate}" />
                <CheckBox Content="Template files *.rte, *.rft"
                          Margin="4"
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsTemplateUpdate}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>

        <GroupBox Header="Saving settings"
                  Margin="4">
            <StackPanel>
                <RadioButton GroupName="SavingSettings"
                             Content="Add a suffix to the file name"
                             Margin="4"
                             IsChecked="{Binding IsAddSuffixSave}" />
                <RadioButton GroupName="SavingSettings" 
                             Content="Save the updated files in a subfolder"
                             Margin="4"
                             IsChecked="{Binding IsSubFolderSave}" />
                <RadioButton GroupName="SavingSettings"
                             Content="Overwrite existing files"
                             Margin="4"
                             IsChecked="{Binding IsOverwriteSave}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>

        <GroupBox Header="Additional settings"
                  Margin="4">
            <StackPanel>
                <CheckBox Content="Delete backup files after update"
                          Margin="4"
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsDeleteBackup}"
                          IsEnabled="{Binding IsDeleteBackupEnable}"/>
                <CheckBox Content="Update families in subfolders"
                          Margin="4"
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsIncludeSubFolders}" />
                <CheckBox Content="Update by ignoring errors"
                          Margin="4"
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsIgnoringErrors}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>

        <Button Content="Select folder with Revit files"
                Height="32"
                Margin="4"
                Command="{Binding SelectFolderButton}">
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
        <ListBox x:Name="ListFolders"
                 Grid.Row="1"
                 Grid.Row="1"
                 MinHeight="80"
                 Margin="8 0"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedDirectories}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFolder}"
                 MouseDoubleClick="ListBox_MouseDoubleClick"
                 KeyDown="ListFolders_KeyDown">
        </ListBox>
    <Button Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Content="Upgrade"
            Height="32"
            MinWidth="160"
            Margin="8"
            Command="{Binding RunBatchUpgraderButton}" />
    <Button Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Content="Cancel"
            Height="32"
            MinWidth="160"
            Margin="8"
            Command="{Binding CancelBatchUpgraderButton}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Is the ListBox the only child of the DockPanel? That would be redundant. What is the parent element of the DockPanel? Please show the relevant XAML parts of the overall layout. Omit all the irrelevant properties of the single elements.

Comment: DockPanel this is another experiment of mine that turned out to be unsuccessful.  I've added the full XAML above in the text. And removed the extra DockPanel.

Comment: The problem is `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` on the Window. Either remove that or set a fixed Height on the ListBox.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you very much, I had completely overlooked that setting. After removing it, I was able to get the behaviour I wanted without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be simple enough. This behavior gave the window property: `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"`. After removing it, the scrollbar appears correctly. Thanks, @Clemens for pointing out my error.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to ditch `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"`, but instead you can just fix the hight of the ListBox control - either by directly setting its Height or MaxHeight property or those its container.

Comment: @Peregrine I had the goal of leaving the ListBox stretchable (only the ListBox element was enlarged when the window was stretched) so that the user could see more rows. If I fix the height the ListBox will not increase. Thank you, for your comment.